# javacomplete2 no muestra campos de objeto

Tags: plugin, vim

Uso vim para programar en Java. Recientemente he descubierto el plugin javacomplete2 y me ha gustado. El problema es que si una clase no aparece como importada, no se me muestran los campos de un objeto de dicha clase. Por lo cual, para clases que pertenezcan al mismo paquete  no me sirve de nada.
 He probado cambiando los valores de la variable g:JavaComplete_SourcesPath
pero no me ha funcionado. Ya no sé que más hacer.

Comment: Lo que debes hacer en este caso es decirle a javacomplete2 que te importe la clase tecleando `<leader>ji`